# Copy-pasting image files into LibreOffice Writer doesn’t work from the Xfce desktop

Tags: xfce, desktop, clipboard, images, libreoffice

I want to copy-paste image files into LibreOffice Writer.

- It **works** fine when copying the files within **Thunar**:
  the image appears in the document.
- It **doesn’t work** when copying the files from the **Xfce desktop**:
  the file path appears in the document.

I tried <kbd>Right-click → Paste</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + v</kbd> (where I can only select "Unformatted text").

Is it possible?

#### Workarounds

- Open the desktop folder with Thunar and copy the image from there.
- Drag and drop the image from the desktop into LibreOffice.
- Use LibreOffice’s menu to insert the image: [<kbd>Insert → Image</kbd>](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Inserting_Pictures)

Comment: Your are dragging to copy into libreoffice? Have you tried pasting using Ctrl+Shift+V?

Comment: @αғsнιη: I use Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v. When pasting with Ctrl+Shift+v, the only option is to paste it as plain text.

Comment: @αғsнιη: I just tested: drag and drop works fine. (Edited the question to mention this, and added the ways I tried to paste the image.)

Comment: The workarounds seem to have become longer than the first revision; Probably better to [self-answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead.